# Can I query Hyperledger Fabric directly from a WebApp?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm really new to Hyperledger and blockchain. From what I understand, the whole meaning of the blockchain is to build decentralized applications, not depending on a single server.

So my question is: Is there a way to query and work with a Fabric node directly from a web browser? I believe Ethereum solves this problem with web3.js.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: No.

Web3.js communicates with Ethereum over JSON RPC and is supported by browsers.

Hyperledger Fabric, on the other hand, uses Protobuf over grpc. Currently, there is no such implementation like web3.js that can communicate directly using a browser with Hyperledger Fabric.

However Hyperledger Burrow, that provides a permissioned version of Ethereum and supports Solidity Smart Contracts does not yet support web3.js, but it is something they have in their roadmap and shall support soon.

Check this for more updates: https://wiki.hyperledger.org/projects/burrow/roadmap_2018_q1

Answer (score 0):

To mimic a network for testing you can use [composer-playground.mybluemix.net](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net)  and to test your assets/transactions once deployed on Fabric, you can use Composer's REST API to make calls to localhost.